# Cubic spline between circles

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I would like to define a spline between some circles as shown in the figure below:

[image]

I want to write the spline mathematically, so I have four coordinates that I can define, but I can't manage to find a good approximation. Can anyone help me to find the coordinates for such a spline, by using the radius (R) and the angle ($\alpha$=60$^\circ$).

If I use the point of intersection between the circles I get a weird curve (please see figure below).

[image]

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you!

EDIT:

The coordinates that I have now are:

```
1.(0,R)
2.(0,2*R-(-(2*R)*sin(60)+2*R)/2)
3.(R-cos(60)),2*R-(-(2*R)*sin(60)+2*R)/2)
4.(R,3*R-(-(2*R)*sin(60)+2*R))
```

They give a good approximation, but still not good enough!

Comment: How good an approximation do you need? If it's just for graphics, two or three cubic segments will work. If it's for high-precision manufacturing, then more might be needed.

Answer (score 1):

No (non-rational) cubic spline segment will approximate this curve well.

Using rational cubic curves, and using *two* segments, you can trace out the curve exactly, but that may not be what you want. The starting point is 
$$
(x(t), y(t)) = \left ( \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \frac{2t}{1+t^2} \right)
$$
which, as $t$ varies from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, traces out the unit circle at the origin. By reparameterizing, translating, and limiting the domain, you can make it trace out either one of your circle-arcs; then by using two copies, you can end up tracing out both.

Comment: I was afraid of that... But what if I try to use multiple quadratic functions instead? So the end of one arc would represent the beginning of the next one. I'm working on it right now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, btw!

Comment: With *enough* quadratics, you can fit it just fine. But you can do so with enough line segments, too -- it's just that it requires a great many. Is there a reason to avoid rational cubics? They're not that tough to work with...

Comment: The reason is... lack of proper knowledge. I don't know how to define "t' from your formulation. I can see that it gives the continuous values for x and y. I would like to extract four points out of the formulation, which would correspond to the four points that one can add in AutoCAD for defining a cubic spline. Am I making any sense?

Comment: When you use four points to define a "cubic spline" in Autocad, do you get a  single cubic segment, or several segments? If a single segment, are the four points the Bezier control points, or does the spline pass though all four of them.